# Error mqtt : Error to loop [65] Transferring data over socket failed: Sending data over the socket failed. Has it been closed?

Tags: php, mqtt

in php (with cakephp) I have 3 different connections like this that I run separately :

```
$connectionSettings = (new \PhpMqtt\Client\ConnectionSettings)
        ->setUsername("username")
        ->setPassword("password")
        ->setConnectTimeout(3)
        ->setUseTls(false);

$mqtt = ClientBuilder::create();
try {
        $io->out(__('Connecting'));
        $mqtt->connect($connectionSettings, true);
        $io->out(__('Connecting'));
 } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $io->error(__('Error to connect {0}', $e->getMessage()));
 }
 
 try {
        $io->out(__('Setup Subscribe Callback'));
        $filter = 'filter';
        $idStartAt = strlen($filter) - 1;
        $mqtt->subscribe($filter, function ($topic, $message) use ($idStartAt, $io) {
            $this->method($topic, $idStartAt, $message, $io);
        }, 0);
 } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $io->error(__('Error to subscribe {0}', $e->getMessage()));
 }

 try {
        $io->out(__('Start loop'));
        $mqtt->loop(true);
 } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $io->error(__('Error to loop {0}', $e->getMessage()));
 }

 try {
        $io->out(__('Disconnecting'));
        $mqtt->disconnect();
 } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $io->error(__('Error to disconnect {0}', $e->getMessage()));
 }
```

I have no errors when I run the 3 commands and it works fine but after several days I get the following error:

```
Error to loop [65] Transferring data over socket failed: Sending data over the socket failed. Has it been closed?
```

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: This error can have many reasons. It basically says that the connection to the MQTT broker is broken or got lost. This can be a simple timeout issue; the broker could be restarted or a change in the network configuration could have occurred (e.g. applying new settings on a managed switch). As these things can happen from time to time, you should design your application in a way which makes this process resilient. In other words, use a supervisor like supervisord or systemd to automatically restart the app(s) in case of errors.